# How to configure Bridge is compatible with mac80211 in adi-linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, bridge, zynq, wifi

I am building Linux kernel in order to run in **ZedBoard + AD9361 (zynq-zed-ad9361-fmcomms2)**.
I had built and tested the driver: "*mac80211*" successfully.

But afterwards, because I want to add and operate an Ethernet to WLAN Bridge, I enabled Bridge in Kernel Config file (`CONFIG_BRIDGE=y; CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER=y;.....`) and rebuilt.

Unfortunately, when I modprobe mac80211, I received the following error :

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mac80211': Invalid argument
```

And when checking *dmesg*, I saw the messages:

```
cfg80211: disagrees about version of symbol __sock_create cfg80211:
Unknown symbol __sock_create (err -22) cfg80211: disagrees about
version of symbol skb_copy_bits cfg80211: Unknown symbol skb_copy_bits
(err -22) ..
```

Everybody, Please help me to resolve the above problem! I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem.

I forgot copying and updating driver object files:*.ko into the directory: /rootfs/lib/modules/adi-linux/ after rebuilding the new Linux kernel.

Good luck to all !